# Minimal surface functional independent on $\theta$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have a minimization problem $F(u(x))=\int_A \sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}dA$, where $A$ is a ring such that $1<|x|<2$. After going to the polar coordinates we obtained:
$$
F(\varphi(r,\theta))=\int_A \sqrt{1+\varphi_r^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\varphi_\theta^2}\ rdrd\theta
$$
and now because of the symmetry the solution is independent of the angle $\theta$, but I do not know how to prove it rigorously to get:
$$
F(\varphi(r))=2\pi\int_1^2\sqrt{1+\varphi_r^2}\ rdr
$$

I suppose that the idea is to show that if we add some variation of the angle it will make things worse:

$$
F(\varphi(r))\leq F(\varphi(r)+d(\varphi(\theta)))
$$
But I do not know if it is a way to do this and how to proceed.

Upd:
To clarify. I understand that **if** $\varphi$ is independent of $\theta$, **then** we have $F(\varphi(r))=2\pi\int_1^2\sqrt{1+\varphi_r^2}\ rdr$, but I do not know how to prove that it is indeed independent, even though it is kind of obvious

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ in the fisrt integral before using polar coordinates ? Otherwise $F[u(x)]$ is a line integral instead of a surface integral.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is independent of $\theta$ thanks to symmetry, then $\varphi_\theta = 0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi$.

Comment: yes, you're right, it is $dxdy$, I shorted the notation as $x=(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: I don't understand how rigorous is "thanks to symmetry", I also have this intuition but my question was -- how to prove it without "thanks to symmetry" in a more precise way

Comment: To clarify. I understand that if $\varphi$ is independent of $\theta$, then we have $F(\varphi(r))=2\pi\int_1^2\sqrt{1+\varphi_r^2}\ rdr$, but I can not prove that it is indeed independent, even though it is kind of obvious

Comment: Little warning : it should also be $\frac{\phi_\theta^2}{r^2}$ instead of $\frac{\phi_\theta}{r^2}$. Then, since the integrand is positive, assuming $\phi_\theta = 0$ to suppress this term permits to lower the final result. A more systematic approach would use the Euler-Lagrange equations associated to the Lagrangian $L = r\sqrt{1+\phi_r^2+\frac{\phi_\theta^2}{r^2}}$.

Comment: You are indeed right, I made a typo, thanks!